# Instantiating a class does not work, constructor parameter did not pass

Tags: java, inheritance, parameters, constructor, polymorphism

I tried to initialize an circle object from my test class, but the parameter(5.5) did not pass. The result is wrong. I tried to debug and find out the radius is 0.00 in circle class, 5.5 did not pass into the Circle class.
Anyone can help me with that?

This is my output:

```
The area of circle is:  3.14
```

This is my test class:

```
public class ShapeTest {
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Circle circle = new Circle(5.5);
            System.out.println(circle);
            }


        }
    }
```

This is my circle class:

```
public class Circle extends TwoDimensionalshape {
        private double radius;

        public Circle(double radius){
            super(radius);
        }

    public void setRadius(double radius){
        this.radius = radius;
    }
    public double getRadius(){
        return radius;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea(){
        return 3.14+getRadius()+getRadius();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("%s %,.2f%n ","The area of circle is: ",getArea());
    }



}
```

This is my super class:

```
public class TwoDimensionalshape implements Area{
        private double radius;
        private double base;
        private double height;

        public TwoDimensionalshape(double radius){
            this.radius = radius;
    }

    public TwoDimensionalshape(double base, double height){
        this.base = base;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }


    public double getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    @Override
    public double getArea(){
        return 1;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "The area is: "+getArea();
    }


}
```

Comment: You have a mathematic mistake in getArea() method. Replace + with *

Comment: I did that to debug, will change it back after I get the value of radius. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `radius` variable in `Circle` *hides* the `radius` variable in `TwoDimensionalshape`.  They are 2 different variables.  Your constructor sets the one in `TwoDimensionalShape`, but `getArea` is using the one in `Circle`.

Remove the `radius` variable in `Circle`.  Let `Circle` inherit `getRadius` by removing that method from `Circle`.  Also in `Circle`, move `setRadius` to `TwoDimensionalShape`.

Also, in `getArea`, multiply the radius twice instead of adding it twice.  You can also use `Math.PI` instead of `3.14`.

```
return Math.PI * getRadius() * getRadius();
```

Comment: I add this.radius = radius in my Circle constructor and it works. So I should not declare variables with the same name in superclass and subclass, right?

Comment: No, you shouldn't add same-name variables in subclasses.  That is the root cause of your problem here.  Adding `this.radius = radius;` in the constructor is not the best solution.  You still have 2 `radius` variables.

Comment: The superclass radius variable is private. So even subclass can't use it without super keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the following line in `Circle` constructor:

```
public Circle(double radius){
    super(radius);
    this.radius = radius; // add this line
}
```

As `radius` is `private` in `TwoDimensionalshape`, you don't have an access to it from the subclass (from `Circle` in that case). You need to set value of `radius` of `Circle` class in constructor of `Circle`, as in your code, it calculated `getArea()` with the `radius` value of `0`.

Another issue - to calculate area properly, you should change:

```
return 3.14 + getRadius() + getRadius();
```

to:

```
return 3.14 * getRadius() * getRadius();
```

Comment: @lanlan Glad that I could help - please keep in mind that **rgettman**'s answer provides much better approach, anyway you might consider my answer as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `private double radius;` from Circle class and it should work. Also change getRadius() method body in Circle class to:
 `return super.getRadius();`

Comment: I add this.radius = radius in my Circle constructor and it works. Thanks for your help :)